# How can I write this C for loop in Python? - what is the best solution?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
for (i = 0; number > 0; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        total = total + number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
}
```

I need to write this in python.
I tried to separate them into 2 loops `while` and `for`.

```
while number > 0:
    for i in range(infinite):
```

But I don't know how to run infinite `for` loop in python.

Here is what I think may be the solution: Is there any better way?

```
i = 0
while number > 0:
    i += 1
    if i % 2 == 0։
        total = total + number % 10
        number /= 10
```

and this is the whole code

```
long number = get_long("Number: ");

int total = 0;
int first2 = 0;
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; number > 0; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        total = total + number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    else
    {
        if (number % 10 < 5)
        {
            total = total + 2 * (number % 10);
            number /= 10;
        }
        else
        {
            total = total + 1 + (2 * number) % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }
    }
    if (number >= 10 && number < 100)
    {
        first2 = number;
    }
}
if (total % 10 == 0)
{
    if ((first2 == 34 || first2 == 37) && i == 15)
    {
        printf("A\n");
    }
    else if ((first2 == 51 || first2 == 52 || first2 == 53 || first2 == 54 || first2 == 55) && i == 16)
    {
        printf("M\n");
    }
    else if (first2 / 10 == 4 && (i == 16 || i == 13))
    {
        printf("V\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }

}
else
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

Comment: Your `python` code doesn't seem to be equivalent to the `c` code. Is this part of the problem?

Comment: Move `i += 1` to the end of the loop

Comment: One way to run a infinite loop is : `while True:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest equivalent of your C/Java code in Python would be this:

```
total = 0
i = 0
while number > 0:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        total += number % 10
        number //= 10
    i += 1
```

This is not very elegant, as you have to rewrite the `for (...;...;...)` loop with a `while` and separate lines for initialization and increment. Note that his is *close* to what you have, but there are two important differences: First, the `i += 1` should be at the end of the loop, as the third block of the `for` is also executed *after* each iteration. Also note the `//` for integer division in Python!

This just calculates the sum of all digits. The `i % 2` part is irrelevant as the `number //= 10` bit is only executed within that block, so it just makes the outer loop run twice as long. If that is indeed what you want, you could simplify it to this, without `i`:

```
while number > 0:
    total += number % 10
    number //= 10
```

Or just this:

```
total = sum(map(int, str(number)))
```

If, however, you want to add every other digit (starting from the end), e.g. `6+4+2` for `123456`, then you have to move the `/= 10` part to the outer loop (in the first version including `i`), i.e. decrease the indentation in Python. The rest remains the same.

Comment: Note: With your now posted full code, you do reduce `number` in each iteration one way or another, so the `i` is not irrelevant and you also do something different than what I inferred (what exactly I'm not sure yet, will check again later).

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve with this code, but looking at the C code you gave, I believe the lines with the 'i' variable are useless: you're looping a certain number of times, but half the time you do nothing; you might as well loop half the times.

The python equivalent of your code would be:

```
# number should be initialized to some value
total = 0
while number > 0:
    total += number % 10
    number //= 10
```

So apart from the 'i' variable, you had the best answer already.

Comment: Assuming OP is using Python 3, it should be `//=` though.

Comment: @tobias_k you're right, of course, I only understood that after reading your own answer, floating point division really made no sense.